# Model callbacks not working with self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, self-referencing-table

I am having a model `Evaluation` that has many sub evaluations (self refential)

```
class Evaluation < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :sub_evaluations, class_name: "Evaluation", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy

  before_save :calculate_score

  def calculate_score
    # do something
  end

end
```

I am creating and updating evaluation with sub evaluations as nested attributes.

`calculate_score` method is triggered on sub evaluation creation but not while updating. I have tried `before_update` and `after_validation`. But nothing seems to be working.

**Evaluation form**

```
= form_for @evaluation do |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for :sub_evaluations do |sub_evaluation|
   ...
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Could you show how you are updating sub evaluations ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. `before_save` is getting called for every child whose content is updated. 
One thing to check is if you have permitted `id` in `sub_evaluations_attributes`

Comment: I have permitted id in sub_evaluations_attributes. I guess you are checking it in Rails 5.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking it in Rails 5.0.0.beta3.

Comment: Check if you are able to reproduce this on console using below steps,



   `evaluation = Evaluation.first`
    `sub_evaluation = evaluation.sub_evaluations.first`

     `sub_evaluation.any_attribute = 'any_value'`

     `evaluation.sub_evaluations = [sub_evaluation]`
     `evaluation.save`

Comment: Yes I am able to reproduce it with an integer field on the console. B/w my rails version is 5.0.0.rc1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118541/discussion-between-rahul-and-yogesh-khater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20150613004201/http://tamersalama.com/2011/11/10/rails-nested-attributes-and-before_save-callbacks) helped me to fix the issue.

Child callback isn't triggered because the parent isn't "dirty".

The solution in the article is to "force" it to be dirty by calling attr_name_will_change! on a parent attribute that, in fact, does not change.

Here is the updated model code:

```
class Evaluation < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :sub_evaluations, class_name: "Evaluation", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy

  before_save :calculate_score

  def calculate_score
    # do something
  end

  def exam_id= val
    exam_id_will_change!
    @exam_id = val
  end

end
```

See [Active Model Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) in the Rails API